# Limitations of modern programming languages for low-level network programming

Tags: programming-languages, sockets, networks

For say a network packet sniffer, are there any of the more modern high level languages such as C# or Java, that would actually be unsuitable or limiting when it would come to constructing a packet sniffer?

From most open source examples which I have encountered, it seems C/C++ are the preferred languages when it comes to network programming.

Would I be limited in using purely C#?

I'm not asking for opinions to what language is best, but I'm asking whether the use of particular languages (**especially** C# or Java) would be a problem.

Comment: The existence of libraries such as [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/) and [Pcap.Net](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net) should answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a few low level networking programs in c#, mainly a protocol stack, and a chat messenger. The only issue I ever had was the overhead that comes along with using a high level language. You can still do all of the low level things like looking at packets, and reading individual bytes. Java & .NET both have built-in support for sockets and byte buffering which is all you really need!

Comment: In one of my university projects, I wrote a recursive DNS resolver using the classes `DatagramSocket`, `DatagramPacket` to send/receive packets, and `ByteBuffer` to parse and build packets. Very simple!

Comment: At university we did all our network programming in Java, and IIRC even ~20 years ago when I was first learning to use the internet we basically used Java for everything.